# Netbeans reports "no library found for namespace" for PrimeFaces tags from Maven

Tags: java, jsf, maven, netbeans, primefaces

I'm using Netbeans 7.3 with OpenJDK 1.7.0_21 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01 on Linux 3.8.8-1-ARCH.

On every Facelet I have

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Netbeans reports `xmlns:p` as "no library found for namespace" and all `<p:xxx>` tags are also not recognized in intellisense.

I'm managing dependencies using Maven. I have the following in my pom:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
</repository>
```

and

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I deploy to a Tomcat server, then everything works fine; PrimeFaces components work as expected.

Comment: *"But when I deploy to a Tomcat server everything works fine, and primefaces components work as expected"* Thus this is just a Netbeans+Maven specific problem.

Comment: Yes I have come to that conclusion too. But someone has to have encountered the same problem.

Comment: I added the relevant `[maven]` tag. I don't do Maven, but I guess that you just need to tell it to download the sources as well instead of only the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the version of Netbeans I was using. The namespaces got renamed and the support wasn't in yet.

see: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228064