# No library found for namespace xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, maven-3, netbeans-7

I am trying to add primefaces for my JSF application using Netbeans IDE. While adding the namespace for primefaces in xhtml page, i am facing the errors as "No library found for namespace xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui".

My Environment setup
JDK 1.7, Maven 3.0.4, Tomcat 7, Primefaces 3.3, Netbeans IDE, JSF 2.1.2

And in pom.xml, i have added the primefaces repo and dependency as

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also i have tried to change the namespace as specified in this [blog]

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
```

It was always not working.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just a NetBeans error, or do you get it after you deploy your app on Tomcat? You can have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262266/netbeans-reports-no-library-found-for-namespace-for-primefaces-tags-from-maven

Comment: @Anand Devaraj..Did you try  `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`? instead of above name space. Cause this is old one.

Comment: @SRy I have tried with xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" and it works fine. This issues is in Netbeans for the first time. When i deploy my app in tomcat, it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Copy primefaces-p.taglib.xml from META-INF in primefaces.jar dependency, to META-INF in your web module:

[Example in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBsnh.png)

Answer (score 2):

There's an [issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228064) in NetBeans, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262266/netbeans-reports-no-library-found-for-namespace-for-primefaces-tags-from-maven) and fixed in version 7.4.
In this case the error should be gone after application is deployed on Tomcat server.

(Posted just to keep the solution suggestions out of the comments.)